# Python descending number

Tags: python

I need to create a program that will take a integer, (e.g. 4586), and return the number with the digits in descending order (e.g. 8654).

```py
num = 4586

num1 = num #num1 is a string

descendingNumber = []

for i in num1:
 for j in i:
   if i < j:
     descendingNumber.append(i)
   else:
     descendingNumber.insert(1,i)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `num1` is not a string. I think you mean `num1 = str(num)`

Comment: When you run this program, you get an error, `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` at `for i in num1:`. What does that tell you? Maybe your assumptions are incorrect?

Comment: If `num1` were a string, `for j in i: if i < j:` wouldn't work. Do you know why? Try putting `print(i, j)` in the innermost loop and see what their actual values would be. Either way, sorting a list is more complicated than this.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask], which includes tips like starting with your own research, forming a specific question, and writing a clear title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That insertion process doesn't look quite right. You can accomplish this in one line using built-ins.

First, we get the individual digits by using `str()`, and then sort them using `sorted()`. This gives us a list of digits, so we then use `''.join()` to turn it back into a string. Finally, we cast the result back into an integer to get our desired output.:

```py
int(''.join(sorted(str(num), reverse=True)))
```

This outputs:

```py
8654
```